# Can you pass a list in an ParamArray parameter

Tags: vb.net, methods, paramarray

I'm was wondering if you can pass a list into a parameter of ParamArray in a method? For ex.

```
dt = ws.getTable("baseDivision.code:1",
    "countryCode:CA",
    "status.code:[1+TO+6]",
    "buType.code:(6+7+8+88)",
    "market.code:[0+TO+*]",
    "region.code:[0+TO+*]",
    "!subDivision.code:null",
    "openDate:[*+TO+NOW%2B1MONTH]")
```

Instead of passing these parameters can you pass a list of strings where each elements contains these parameters.

So kinda like this

```
dt = ws.getTable(aListOfStringParamters)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but the argument must be an array.  If the argument is some other kind of enumerable list, then you can use LINQ's `ToArray` extension method to convert it:

```
dt = ws.getTable(aListOfStringParamters.ToArray())
```

Comment: @Fabio Well, that depends on whether or not you would refer to an array as a "list".  Arrays do contain a list of items, so in a general way they are.  But also, since in the .NET Framework, arrays actually do implement the `IList` interface, it's also rather technically accurate to refer to them as lists too. :)

Comment: thanks @StevenDoggart This has saved me hundreds of lines of code, I didn't think about it that way :)